# Static function behavior and __toString magic method

Tags: php, oop, static

Here is a cut down snippet of my code

```
namespace classes\tools\html;

class html{
    public static function element($tag) {
        return new element($tag);
    }
}

class element{


      //......

    public function __toString() {


        $element = "<$this->tag";
        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $element.= " $attribute=\"$value\"";
        }
        if ($this->selfClosing) {
            $element.="/>";
            return $element;
        }

        $element.=">$this->html</$this->tag>";

        return $element;
    }

}


$html = new html();
```

what's  confusing me is if I call element with:

```
$html::element('a')->attr('href','/home/')->html('home');
```

It will return

```
'<a href="/home/">home</a>"
```

but if I call it with:

```
$html->element('a')->attr('href','/home/')->html('home');
```

It will return an `element` Object

So my question is why does calling it statically with the `::` operator invoke the `__toString` method but the latter does not?

**Edit**

[link to full element class](http://pastebin.com/XjAVyLda)

Comment: Try replacing return with var_dump(), my guess is that it is that return is triggering __toString in static context. It is however a guess and I would be very pleased if someone could give a more wellfounded explanation.

Comment: Very interesting question btw

Comment: @Digitalis yes I probably should have mentioned I had done a var_dump, which shows the contents of the element object

Comment: Then I'd suspect the return statement calls __toString in static context.

Comment: `It will return` -- what does it mean? Please, add the way of getting output values.

Answer (score 0):

the element() function of class html is static, so you do not want to create an instance of html, but instead call your function like this:

```
echo html::element('a')->...
```

Sometimes it will be necesssary to cast return value to get a string, because element function returns an element object:

```
$var = (string)html::element('a')->...
```

**NB: notice I dont use $html**

Comment: actually `echo $html->element('span')...` will invoke the to string method, where as `$string= $html->element('span')...` will not